# How to make channel client in views.py?

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I am making a chatbot in views.py will receive an HTTP request by the user and views.py interacts with the bot and return to the user. I am using channels to communicate between views.py and chatbot API. following is the views code and channel consumer code.

```
#views.py

@api_view(['POST'])
def conv(request):
    ws = create_connection(url)
    ws.send({"message":request.data["msg"]})
    rec = ws.recv()
    return {"msg" : rec}

#consumers.py
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

After receiving from the channel the connection disconnects and I am unable to maintain chat session on the consumer end.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar setup and I think code for pushing to consumer is wrong. I use function integrated to django channels

so to push some data to room you can use

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(room_group_name, data)
```

Comment: will the channel itself make a new group on the basis of the name I send?

Comment: what about receiving from the channel? how can we do that? As I want some text processing to happen and return it to the chat room which will be read from views.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should send some message using javascript for this

Comment: but user can only connect to the api using http request as it is a third party api. I can't connect the template to consumer using websocket directly.